# Using text browser on Linux to display proxy information

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

How can I store proxy information permanently for a text
mode browser such as [links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/)?

Comment: Please address the formatting

Answer (score 1):

For links:

- press ESC to get to the menus
- Setup | Network options | Proxies
- enter proxy information
- OK
- OK
- ESC
- Save options

This gets stored in $HOME/.links2/links.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Links like many other console utilities can use global proxy configuration or per user proxy configuration. Assuming you are using linux you should use the command "export http_proxy=http://your_proxy_host_name:proxy_port" followed by "export https_proxy=$http_proxy" if you use the same combination for http/https. if you want to make that configuration global and permanent you have to create an executable file called proxy.sh in "/etc/profile.d" (Centos 6.x) and put the same commands above in that file. When a user logs on that file will be executed and proxy configuration will be automatically configured for you.